# Why Codeigniter cache db is not working in get query?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hi I need to cache only one query in my CI app.
I dont understand what to do now. For example I have this in my config/database.php

```
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = APPPATH . 'cache';
```

And this is my model:

```
public function get_languages() {
        $this->db->cache_on();
        $this->db->save_queries = TRUE;
        log_message("error", "getLanguages!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        $this->db->from('tbl_language'); 
        $result = $this->db->get();
        $results = $result->result_array();
        log_message("error", $this->db->last_query());
        return $results;
}
```

I always see the query is executed in DB.
Some help please! What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below code worked me!

```
public function get_languages() {
        $this->db->cache_on();
        $this->db->save_queries = TRUE;
        log_message("error", "getLanguages!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        $this->db->from('tbl_language'); 
        $result = $this->db->get();
        $results = $result->result_array();
        var_dump($results);//print for checking
        $count = $result->num_rows();
        log_message("error", $this->db->last_query());
        if($count>0)
        {
            foreach($results as $list)
            {
                echo $list['id'];
            }           
        }
}
```